# How to stop animation in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-animation

ysize.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:shareInterpolator="@android:interpolator/linear"
    >
    <scale
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromYScale="10dp"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="40dp"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:duration="480"
        >
    </scale>
</set>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Animation input_v1;
ImageView in_v1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        input_v1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.ysize);  //Animation initialization
        in_v1 = findViewById(R.id.i_v1);        //image,textview,button initialization
        in_v1.startAnimation(input_v1);        //Start animation
    }
}
```

The above code work and start the Animation.
But I want to stop this animation.
and other important functions for animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work for me.

```
        in1_v.clearAnimation();                //Stop animation
```

Answer (score 0):

//How you start

```
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.ysize);
          rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
iv.startAnimation(rotation);
```

//You do your stuff while it spins

```
...
```

//You tell it not to repeat again

```
rotation.setRepeatCount(0);
```